# Thumbnailator how to write resulting thumbnail to a separate folder

Tags: java, thumbnails

I am using thumbnailator java lib to generate thumbnails of uploaded images with this one line of code

```
Thumbnails.of(bigFileName+fileExtn)
    .size(160, 160)
    .toFile(new File(newFolderName + thumbnailFileName + fileExtn));
```

I get a `FileNotFoundException` just before it creates a new file.

but when I save the file to thumbs folder and then overwrite it with the thumbnail file it works. how can I write the thumbnail to a directory where it does not exist already?

Comment: what are `newFolderName`, `thumbnailFileName` and `fileExtn` exactly? any chance you forgot the delimiter between folder and filename? `new File(newFolderName, thumbnailFileName + "." + fileExtn)` looks more reasonable to me than your code.

Comment: those are strings which I'm concatenating to make a path to file. I agree there is a delimeter between the file names and extension. my problem is that I am not able to save the generated thumbnail to a different folder. I want to store thumbnails in a different folder

I got the example from here 

code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 0):

you probably forgot the slash between `newFolderName` and `thumbnailFileName` but we can't really tell unless you tell us their contents.